# Remove double space/tab combinations using Re in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to replace all instances where there are consecutive tabs and/or spaces in Python with a single space, using the Re module. I do not want to remove new lines (which rules out the \s commend). At the moment I have:

```
    formateed_string = re.sub("\t+" , " ", formateed_string)            
    formateed_string = re.sub(" +" , " ", formateed_string)         
    formateed_string = re.sub("\t " , " ", formateed_string)    
    formateed_string = re.sub(" \t" , " ", formateed_string)
```

i.e this first checks for consecutive spaces, then consecutive tabs, then tab/space, then space/tab. this seems to normally work, however occasionally leaves behind a double-space (which I guess means there are unusual contamination of tabs/spaces which the above does not fully remove).

Is there a simple/more elegant way of achieving this?

[n.b. running Python 2.7]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below regex would replace consecutive tabs or spaces with a single whitespace. Note that, it won't convert a single tab into a space.

```
formatted_string = re.sub("[\t ]{2,}", " ", formatted_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

In a regular expression, if you put characters inside square brackets, it means "any one of these characters". So `"[\t ]+"` will match any sequence of tabs and/or spaces.

```
formatted_string = re.sub("[\t ]+", " ", formatted_string)
```

Comment: Won't this remove all tabs and spaces, not just two or more consecutive ones since `+` means _one_ or more?